# Can I make a transition on an SVG attribute that is not CSS?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, transition

I have an SVG that I would like to transition to extend when the mouse hovers over it, and ease back to its normal size when the mouse is not hovering. Because it is not adjusted through CSS, I can't figure out how to make that transition happen.

https://codepen.io/BrendanOB/pen/LYYepQQ

^ A link to an example of what I've got so far

Im new to javascript, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

I have already tried CSS transform scale and matrix, without working results.

```
<style>
 .st2{fill:#E5CACA;}
 .st3{fill:none;stroke:#FFF;stroke-width:17;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>

<g id="Layer_2">
   <line class="st3" x1="500" y1="142" x2="500" y2="95"/>
   <line onmouseover="bigLine()" onmouseleave="smallLine()" id="move" class="st3" x1="518.2" y1="142.9" x2="521.8" y2="96.1"/>
   <line id="stretch" class="st3" x1="536" y1="144.7" x2="544" y2="98.3"/>
</g>

<script>
 function bigLine(){
     var lines = document.querySelector('#Layer_2')
     var l = lines.querySelector('#move')
     console.log(l);
     l.transition = "all 2s";
     l.setAttribute("y2", "26");
   }

   function smallLine(){
     var lines = document.querySelector('#Layer_2')
     var l = lines.querySelector('#move')
     console.log(l);
     l.transition = "all 2s";
     l.setAttribute("y2", "96");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: CSS animation only applies to CSS properties. You could use SMIL here.

Comment: You can use css animation on inline svg. I think You need to change how to animate it.
Maybe give a try to stroke dasharray and stroke dashoffset. you can also animate with css js or smil

https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert Longson commented you can use SMIL animations: Inside the line `#move` there are 2 `<animate>` elements: the first for the `mouseover` and the second for `mouseleave`.

The first animation is changing the value of the x2 attribute of the line `from="96.1" to="26"`. The second element has no `from` attribute but is animating the value of the y2 `to="96.1"`  The duration of both animations is `dur="1s"` and `fill="freeze"` is similar to the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` from CSS.

I hope it helps.

```css
.st2 {
  fill: #e5caca;
}
.st3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 17;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;">
  <g id="Layer_2">
 <line class="st3" x1="500" y1="142" x2="500" y2="95"/>
    <line id="move" class="st3" x1="518.2" y1="142.9" x2="521.8" y2="96.1">
       <animate
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="y2" 
        from="96.1" to="26" 
        begin="mouseover"
        dur="1s" 
        fill="freeze" />
       <animate
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="y2" 
        to="96.1" 
        begin="mouseleave"
        dur="1s" 
        fill="freeze" />
    </line>
 <line id="stretch" class="st3" x1="536" y1="144.7" x2="544" y2="98.3"/>
</g> 
</svg>
```